# Custom binned colorbar: can't set tick labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

I'am trying to create my own binned colorbar, but I can't set my own tick labels, that remain fixed.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (10, 1))

cmapor = plt.get_cmap('jet')
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap([ i for i in cmapor(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))])
bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, 6)[:-1]
labels = ['0', '2.5', '5', '7.5', '10']
cb2 = mcolorbar.ColorbarBase(plt.gca(), cmap = cmap, orientation = 'horizontal', spacing='proportional', extendfrac='auto')
cb2.ax.set_xticks = bounds
cb2.ax.set_xticklabels = labels

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

gives [image]

I would like to have no tick label on the last one, and the other ones labeled as mentioned in `labels`.

Note also that the ticks for 0.2 and 0.4 are not perfectly centered on the separation between the colors .. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that in `cb2.ax.set_xticks = bounds`, `set_xticks` is a function. By executing the equal assignment, you replace that function with an array. But what you really want to do, is to *call* the function, so you need `cb2.ax.set_xticks(bounds)`. The same happens with `set_xticklabels`.

For colorbars, instead of `cb2.ax.set_xticks(bounds)`, recent versions of matplotlib prefer that you'd call `cb2.set_ticks(bounds)` (although the old way still keeps functioning). Similarly, `cb2.set_ticklabels(labels)` is now preferred to set the labels.

About *"the ticks for 0.2 and 0.4 are not perfectly centered on the separation"*: this seems to be some rounding error. Leaving out `spacing='proportional'` helps here.

The adapted code, including importing the libraries would look like:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors as mcolors
from matplotlib import colorbar as mcolorbar

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 1))

cmapor = plt.get_cmap('jet')
cmap = mcolors.ListedColormap([i for i in cmapor(np.linspace(0, 1, 5))])
cb2 = mcolorbar.ColorbarBase(plt.gca(), cmap=cmap, orientation='horizontal', extendfrac='auto')
bounds = np.linspace(0, 1, 6)[:-1]

labels = ['0', '2.5', '5', '7.5', '10']
cb2.set_ticks(bounds)
cb2.set_ticklabels(labels)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]